# Websocket bufferedAmount for progress bar

Tags: javascript, websocket

I'm trying to find if there's a way to show a loading status(maybe a progress bar) when I send large files(100MB+) using a Websocket connection. So far I was thinking about `bufferedAmount`

I have this code

```
setInterval(function () {
  if (ws.bufferedAmount > 0)
      console.log(ws.bufferedAmount);
}, 50);
ws.send(file); //100MB file
```

This prints to console only once, and it's the exact file size. `ws.bufferedAmount` doesn't return the amount of bytes that are not send? For example if 10Mb were sent, `ws.bufferedAmount` should return 90MB.

Comment: The WebSocket.bufferedAmount read-only property returns the number of bytes of data that have been queued using calls to send() but not yet transmitted to the network. This value resets to zero once all queued data has been sent. This value does not reset to zero when the connection is closed; if you keep calling send(), this will continue to climb.